# Duplication of rows in Excel stored procedure call

Tags: vba, excel

I have a stored procedure call which is duplicating rows through Excel, I think it has to do with the method I am using for the copy from record set. The data when the query is run manually outputs the correct data.

```
Private Sub Refresh_Click()
    Dim Conn As ADODB.Connection, RecordSet As ADODB.RecordSet

    Dim Command As ADODB.Command
    Dim ConnectionString As String, StoredProcName As String
    Dim StartDate As ADODB.Parameter, EndDate As ADODB.Parameter

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Set Conn = New ADODB.Connection
    Set RecordSet = New ADODB.RecordSet
    Set Command = New ADODB.Command

    ' I blanked out the details here as they are not required as this is working
    ConnectionString = "PROVIDER=SQLOLEDB;DATA SOURCE=xxxx;INITIAL CATALOG=xxxx; User Id=xxxx;Password=xxxx;"

    On Error GoTo CloseConnection

    Conn.Open ConnectionString
    SellStartDate = Format(Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B2").Value2, "yyyy-mm-dd")
    SellEndDate = Format(Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B3").Value2, "yyyy-mm-dd")
    StoredProcName = "fsp_PLReportByDates"

    With Command
        .ActiveConnection = Conn
        .CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
        .CommandText = StoredProcName
    End With

    Set StartDate = Command.CreateParameter("@DateFrom", adDBDate, adParamInput, , SellStartDate)
    Set EndDate = Command.CreateParameter("@DateTo", adDBDate, adParamInput, , SellEndDate)

    Command.Parameters.Append StartDate
    Command.Parameters.Append EndDate    
    Set RecordSet = Command.Execute    

    Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A7").CopyFromRecordset RecordSet
    For intColIndex = 0 To RecordSet.Fields.Count - 1
       Range("A6").Offset(0, intColIndex).Value = RecordSet.Fields(intColIndex).Name
    Next


    RecordSet.Close
    Conn.Close
    On Error GoTo 0
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Exit Sub

    CloseConnection:
     Application.ScreenUpdating = True
     MsgBox "SQL Stored Procedure Did Not Execute Sucessfully!", vbCritical, "SQL Error"
     Conn.Close

End Sub
```

Comment: You are dumping your recordset as-is here: `Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A7").CopyFromRecordset RecordSet` to cell `A7`. If there are duplicates, it's because of your recordset. Fix that and the duplicates go away. Can't help more than that since I have no idea what is in that proc, your schema, or your data. The only other possibility is that you aren't clearing out old data before dumping the recordset so your just pasting shorter data over longer data. At any rate, this code is not the problem. Everything is fine here.

Comment: When I run the data there are no duplicates

Comment: What does "Run the data" mean?

Comment: @JNevill sorry it means when i run it in sql management studio there are no duplicates of the stored proc

Comment: Probably, maybe, possibly what's happening here is that you have data in cell `A7` (and right and down to make the range) and then you run this macro. It just dumps the new recordset over the top of the old. If that olderrecordset/range was bigger than the new one, then the old data will still be there wherever the new recordset was not big enough to overwrite making it appear that there are duplicates. Try clearing that entire range between runs and see if the duplicates clear up. If that's not the case and this recordset is always the same size, then I still think it's the proc.

Comment: @JNevill is there a clear command to be able to do this at all ?. I think you could be correct in that assumption.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that your old recordset/previous pull is bigger than your new one and when you drop the new one over the old one, some of the old records are still present in your sheet...

Make a named range that grows dynamically with your data. Assuming you have 10 columns from your Proc coming back and any number of rows, make a named range called `rng_PLReportByDates` and set it to:

```
=OFFSET(Sheet1!$A$7, 0, 0, COUNTA(Sheet1!$A$7:$A$5000)+1, 10)
```

This will create a named range that has 10 columns and up to 4993 rows. I assume that's plenty for your recordset, otherwise bump that `5000` to whatever makes sense. The `+1` is there just to insure that if the range is completely empty (no values) that this formula will return at least 1 row, otherwise you will error out.

Then... Just before you run:

```
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A7").CopyFromRecordset RecordSet
```

Add this:

```
Range("rng_PLReportByDates").ClearContents
```

You can also change that `CopyFromRecordset` to use your new dynamically sized named range:

```
Range("rng_PLReportByDates").CopyFromRecordset Recordset
```

---

I use this method every time I dump a recordset to a worksheet. I create a dynamically sized named range using that same formula, and then I `.ClearContents` and `.CopyFromRecordset` to it.

If your number of columns changes, then you can just add a `Counta()` formula to that last parameter in the named range formula:

```
=OFFSET(Sheet1!$A$7, 0, 0, COUNTA(Sheet1!$A$7:$A$5000)+1, COUNTA(Sheet1!$A$7:$IV$7)+1)
```

---

As far as the header is concerned, you may want to adjust the named range to go after row `6`. Then you can do:

```
 Range("rng_PLReportByDates").ClearContents
 Range("rng_PLReportByDates").Offset(1).CopyFromRecordset Recordset
```

And then do your range work just the same.

Comment: Sorry the offset says illegal charchter i not quite sure how to implemnt that

Comment: @DavidB I've updated it. Should work now. I have no idea what was wrong with the original attempt, but it's working as epxected here.